# python list all combiniations without itertools

Tags: python, combinations

- I just want to make all combination of list(two size)
- for example: input= [1, 2, 3] => output = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
- how can i make this code more concise and simple?(one-liner?)
- it doesn't mean list compreshension.

#### my code

```
def all_combinations(input_lst):
    return_lst=[]
    for i in range(0, len(input_lst)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(input_lst)):
            return_lst.append([input_lst[i], input_lst[j]])
    return return_lst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(input_lst[i], input_lst[j]) for i in xrange(len(input_lst) - 1) for j in xrange(i + 1, len(input_lst))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,]
=> [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

1. use `enumerate`

```
[ (x,y) for (i,y) in enumerate(l)  for x in l[i+1:] ]
```

2. use `index`

```
[ (x,y) for y in l  for x in l[l.index(y)+1:] ]
```

Comment: The example using `enumerate` creates unnecessary copies of `l` when you do `l[i + 1:]`. The second example does a linear search in `l` for `y` and also creates copies of `l`.

Comment: @letmutx Oh, I missed about that. Thank you for comment.